# Creating my own Ruby class

Tags: ruby, class, methods

I was doing a tutorial how to create my own class.

My goal is to run the function `foo.caps?` and see "Yes" or "No" to indicate whether the string in `foo` is all capital letters or not.

I can't seem to find that section of the tutorial or a good way to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class String
   def caps?
       self == self.upcase
   end
end
```

This extends the String class with a method that can determine if it is uppercase.

```
"FOO".caps? => true
```

Comment: This is a far more elegant solution than mine. :)

Comment: I feel like I'm never fast enough to actually answer questions for reputation.  I guess I like out on this one.  Made my evening.  Thanks for the compliment.

Comment: Hahaha. I know the feeling. And you bet on the compliment. :)

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what answer you're actually looking for, but if I had to guess at it, I would say that you merely need to create your class as such;

```
class Caps

  def is_caps(string_in)?
    if string_in.upcase?
      "yes"
    else
      "no"
    end
  end

end
```